# When an entity has a Spring Data Repository, the LoadTimeWeaving for this entity doesnt work

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, aspectj, aspects

For example, the `User` entity :

```
@Configurable
@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
public class User extends AbstractAggregateRoot<User> implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Autowired
    @Transient
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    @Transient
    private EmailRepository emailRepository;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String nickname;

    @Version
    @Column(columnDefinition = "timestamp")
    @Source(value = SourceType.DB)
    private Timestamp ts;

    public void doSavedComplete() {
        UserSavedEvent event = new UserSavedEvent();
        event.setUser(this);
        event.setTs(new Date());
        andEvent(event);
        userRepository.save(this);
    }

    @Data
    public static class UserSavedEvent {
        private User user;
        private Date ts;
    }
}
```

and it's repository :

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

When I create a new `User` object:

```
User ob = new User();
```

the user's `userRepository` and `emailRepository` are `null`,
because `User` and `Email` have respective `Repository` classes, `UserRepository` and `EmailRepository`;

When I use another class `UserAggregateRoot` which has no Spring Data JPA Repository, the load time weave works great:

```
@Configurable
@Entity
public class UserAggregateRoot extends AbstractAggregateRoot<User> implements Serializable {
    @Autowired
    @Transient
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    @Transient
    private EmailRepository emailRepository;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String nickname;

    @Version
    @Column(columnDefinition = "timestamp")
    @Source(value = SourceType.DB)
    private Timestamp ts;
}
```

`UserAggregateRoot` has no `Repository`, so when I create a new `UserAggregateRoot` object, the fields of `UserAggregateRoot`, `UserRepository` and `EmailRepository` are not `null`;

So I would like to know why? Is it a bug?

Comment: Could you please point a link to the feature you want to utilize here? Also, the configuration you are using might be helpful.

Comment: Oh I think I found it: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-atconfigurable right? Do you happen to see messages matching this in the log: "Instances of @Configurable objects created before the aspect has been configured will result in a message being issued to the debug log and no configuration of the object taking place. "?

Comment: thanks,I have read the doc that link above point; Now ,I know about it a little；so  I have a new question, the User class is a hibernate entity, it's not a spring bean;I try to configure annotation Configurable and DependsOn on User class, it doesn't work; so what should I do, can I Inject UserRepository into User object;@JensSchauder

Comment: `@Configurable` will not work with Spring AOP, it will only work if you use AspectJ directly, with spring-aspects/`AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect` correctly weaved into your code (`User` class in your particular example).

Comment: thanks,I think that I should learn aspectj first.@Fekete,@Jens